# how to point to a member function in a global function in C++?

Tags: c++, opengl, mfc

Now i am writing a MFC program with opengl in it. And when i tried to combine opengl with MFC, i come across some problems:
First, I defined a class named:**CSCommTestDlg**, and defined a member function with codes as follows:

```
void CSCommTestDlg::OpglMain(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    glutDisplayFunc(displayCude);
}
```

displayCube is also a member function of class CSCommTestDlg, and glutDisplayFunc is a global funcion(an opengl function), the function declarations of glutDisplayFunc is as follows:

```
GLUTAPI void APIENTRY glutDisplayFunc(void (GLUTCALLBACK *func)(void));
```

Yes, just as you can see, the parameter of glutDisplayFunc is a function pointer, and i made it point to a member function **displayCube**, which seems illegal, and i got an error like that:

```
error C2664: 'glutDisplayFunc' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'void (void)' to 'void (__cdecl *)(void)'
    None of the functions with this name in scope match the target type
```

seems that i can't point to a member function in a global function, but i need it. How to fix it ?

Comment: How about [`mem_fn`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/mem_fn)?

Comment: I personally would use a library other than glut, or make a framework with a bunch of static functions (callbacks) that owns some sort of Game object that has matching function calls to those callbacks. So a sort of interface between glut and your game. (I guess I made the assumption you're writing a game haha)

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: How would that help the questioner?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

glutDisplayFunc takes a global function, so, simply put, you can't make it take a member function pointer.

One solution would be to mark displayCube as static, but that kinda ruins the point of having a class in the first place.

Another option would be to declare a global function as the glut display callback, and then inside that function, call the displayCube member function of your CSCommTestDlg object - if you can get hold of a global pointer to it.

Answer (score 1):

> Now i am writing a MFC program with opengl in it. And when i tried to combine opengl with MFC.

**If you're using MFC or another toolkit, don't use GLUT!** GLUT is not a part of OpenGL and you're not required to use it.

> and i made it point to a member function displayCube, which seems illegal, and i got an error like that:

Naturally. because a member function requires a class instance to be called with. If you look at the generated machine code it looks not unlike as if there was a pointer to the class instance passed as first parameter. So what you actually needed was a so called "closure", *a feature* simply *not supported by C++.*

It is possible to emulate closures with some dynamically generated code trickery. But *in your case this is not neccessary.* **GLUT and other toolkits don't mix.**